# IOS Reachibility in whole app and just on on view load

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, reachability

I've added the following code to the viewDidLoad of my view controller:

```
let reachability: Reachability
        do {
            reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to create Reachability")
            return
        }

        reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
            // this is called on a background thread, but UI updates must
            // be on the main thread, like this:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
                    print("Reachable via WiFi")
                } else {
                    print("Reachable via Cellular")
                }
            }
        }
        reachability.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
            // this is called on a background thread, but UI updates must
            // be on the main thread, like this:
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print("Not reachable")
            }
        }

        do {
            try reachability.startNotifier()

        } catch {
            print("Unable to start notifier")
        }
```

It is notifying me of when the view loads however not when the state changes after the load. I'm wondering how to expand this so that I can have a notification anywhere in the application an not just on when the view loads as the internet may come back after a view loads.

Thanks

Comment: Am I wrong or how can you declare a constant with its type but without the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the reachability variable as instance variable and not only as local variable within a function. You could further use notifications to make the information available across your app. Just make sure the instance containing the reachability variable lives during the lifecycle of your app.

Answer (score 0):

start reachability in AppDelegate and make it notify all registered observers creating and posting a notification, so you can register every controller you need, as "BostonMacOSX" suggested.

Comment: any instructino on how to do that....been developing for a few weeks in iOS/swift

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create something along the lines of a connectivity controller that manages all reachability related events & holds the instance itself. Then this controller can fire events to all listening view controllers about changes in internet connectivity. Initialize and start the reachability notifier in your app delegate after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: I move the whole block to the app delegate you suggested. Is that enough to "centralize" things?